# iOS Automation Testing on AWS

Tags: automated-testing, mobile-automation, ios, aws

**Background**:

I have been searching how can I install an `.ipa` programmatically on a real iPhone, and all answers are "it's not possible".

So I was wondering, iOS automation cannot be completely automated? There is always a manually intervention required to install the app (new .ipa build) on a phone.

**Question**: Is there a way to automate the entire process so that it can be run in the cloud, like on Amazon AWS?

I am using: Java, AWS T4 X large, Node.js, Appium, Maven, XCode

Answer (score 2):

You can save 90% of the time if you just use [testRigor](https://testrigor.com) instead of Appium. It runs in the cloud and all you need to do to kickoff new tests is just to upload (via UI or API) a new version of your app.

Disclaimer: I'm a co-founder of testRigor.

Answer (score 0):

There's a cloud platform called [pcloudy](https://www.pcloudy.com/) that supports Appium based automation on both iOS and android. They have many physical devices that can be accessed for manual or automated testing through their cloud based platform.

I'm not affiliated with them, have used them occasionally.